# How to redirect stderr output to a file in xamarin.ios app?

Tags: xcode, debugging, logging, xamarin.ios

Am able to redirect stdout to a seperate file in xamarin.iOS but how to redirect stderr output? Is there any way in xcode/mac to view the iOS app's stderr log?

Thanks,
Ravi

Comment: how did you redirect the stdout?

Comment: By using Console I/O Streams we can do it ,please refer the Console class documentation https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/System.Console/